# On-Click Shortcut to Open File in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, shortcut, spotlight, dock

There's plenty of MacOS shortcuts for *opening* the finder, like  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>O</kbd>  or whatnot, but I'm looking for a shortcut to hold down, and then, on a click, it will open finder to that file's location. Does such a shortcut exist? This is to specifically avoid the problem of (relatively) long combinations like doc apps I have to right click, press 'options', then press 'show in finder'.

Ideally, I'm looking for solutions which don't use third-party software and either are already existing shortcuts or ones I can enable via Mac's programs or settings. Ideally it should work for apps on the dock, spotlight search, aliases, and other possibilities.

Comment: Apps in the Dock have a "Show in Finder" option; You can Command click on a Spotlight search result to reveal it in the Finder. Where else are you seeing the file whose location you want to discover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  is almost global for 'reveal in Finder'.
It works from Spotlight & Find.
I'm not sure when this changed, but in Ventura it also works for an Alias.

In Mojave, for an Alias, 'Reveal Original' is  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>  which is useful for an app or doc, but for a folder, double-clicking will open the original anyway.

I don't know of any way from the Dock to speed up the process.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out ⌘ R works for Doc items! Also, ⌃⌥ ⌘ A doesn't work for me, is that one to enable in a shortcuts setting?

Comment: I don't see it in Keyboard > Shortcuts, so I don't think I've added it as a 'special'. In Finder, it's in the Edit menu, but only active if you have an Alias selected, of course.

Comment: Ah… just checked on Ventura [I was on Mojave before] & it seems they've merged the two functions.  ⌘ R seems to now work for both.

Comment: Well thank you for the help! Is there a nice master list of shortcuts btw?

Comment: There are more than you can probably hope to remember at https://support.apple.com/HT201236 Wish you luck :)